# Uncaught TypeError: _moment2.default.date is not a function in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

When I try to use a date from Moment.js in the constructor, componentWillMount, or componentDidMount, I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: _moment2.default.date is not a function
```

I am not using Webpack or any specific build tool outside of npm.  Here is my relevant code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Moment from 'moment';

export default class Date extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { day: '',
                   month: '',
                   year: '',
                   weekday: ''
                 };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setDate();
  }

  setDate() {
    this.state.day = Moment.date();
    this.state.month = Moment.format('MMM');
    this.state.year = Moment.year();
    this.state.weekday = Moment.format('dddd');
  }
```

Is this because Moment hasn't fully been loaded when the component is rendered, or is it something else?  How can I get this fixed?

When I call Moment just in the render() function, I don't get this error.  But, I need the date information in the state so that I can update other app components based on the date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Way you are setting the state is not proper, and use Moment like this: `Moment().`, try this:

```
setDate() {
      this.setState({
           day : Moment().date(),
           month : Moment().format('MMM'),
           year : Moment().year(),
           weekday : Moment().format('dddd')
      });
  }
```

Comment: Doh.  Thank you.  Heads up, you used `=` instead of `:` in this answer. :)